# How to update sum of array elements in json in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 8.0.22
My sample table be like

| id | students | total_marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"students":[{"marks":100},{"marks":100},{"marks":100},{"marks":100}]} |  |

After update it should be

| id | students | total_marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"students":[{"marks":100},{"marks":100},{"marks":100},{"marks":100}]} | 400 |

I ahve to add all the marks in that json. I am able to write a stored procedure for that.
I am trying to do it in one query.
How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: I had miss the incremental id column. I have updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally answering my own question.

Please refer [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html).
`JSON_TABLE()` takes json, path to array and columns with path to required field and converts it to a table format. we can use that table  same as other table in that query.

```
update sample s
set s.total_marks = (
                 select sum(t.marks)
                 from JSON_TABLE(s.students, '$.students[*]' columns(marks int path '$.marks'))
                 as temp_table t 
                 )
where s.id = 1;
```